# Interpolation of the data file

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

Hi I want to interpolate the data from an .asc file, but I am getting an error:
**ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.**
Below this line is minimal code and here [data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JFsRHtYxppvqaP8DUdC0PsecxpVv0rv3)
 is the data file which I want to interpolate.

Here is the code:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dataxx = np.loadtxt('100mK-Rxx.asc')
B1 = dataxx[0:158, 0] 
Rxx1 = dataxx[0:158,3] 
f = interp1d(B1, Rxx1)
f2 = interp1d(B1, Rxx1, kind='cubic')

xnew = np.linspace(0.05, 7.9, num=1000, endpoint=True)
plt.plot(B1, Rxx1, 'o', xnew, f(xnew), '-', xnew, f2(xnew), '--')
plt.legend(['data', 'linear', 'cubic'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear; one of your new `x_new` values is outside of the original range of `x` values. If you want to use extrapolation, set `fill_value` to `extrapolate`.

```
f = interp1d(B1, Rxx1, fill_value='extrapolate')
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) for more info (although there isn't much on the extrapolation...)

Comment: Thanks, I was not very careful and somehow it does not seem to take the very first data point which was there in data file, but anyways I changed the range and it works fine.